# Number.format calculation with map

Tags: html, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am trying to show the number minus 20%. The number is in a map and I am not ale to get the value from there.

This is not working:

```html
 <div class="row p-3 ml-1" th:each="r : ${roomTypes}">
  <div th:with="price=*{r.value}"  th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal({price} * 0.8)}">x</div>
```

This is also not working

```html
  <div th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal({r.value} * 0.8)}">x</div>
```

Is there a way to get this value in Thymeleaf?
Or another way I can make this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`#numbers` utility object](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#numbers) doesn't have a method `formatDecimal(number)`.  Did you mean `formatDecimal(number, minIntegerDigits, decimalDigits)`?

In the expression `th:with="price=*{r.value}"` -- when you use `*{r.value}`, the asterisk specifies that you are [working on a selected object (defined with `th:object`)](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#numbers#expressions-on-selections-asterisk-syntax), but I don't see a `th:object`.  In this case, you should just be using a regular `${...}` expression.

Finally, your `th:text` expression `th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal({price} * 0.8)}"` isn't valid syntax.  In general, you shouldn't be nesting curly brackets `{` and `}`.

The corrected Thymeleaf should look something like:

```
<div class="row p-3 ml-1" th:each="r : ${roomTypes}">
  <div th:with="price=${r.value}"  th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(price * 0.8, 1, 2)}">x</div>
</div>
```